# Adding A button and a TextView for each Line of a ListView

Tags: android, listview, button, android-listview, textview

I am currently working on a very basic android application and have encountered an obstacle I cannot solve on my own.

In my application I want to have a start screen with a ListView. In each Line of this ListView there should be a Button and a TextView. I want to have approximately 5 Lines. When you click on each of the Button you should be able to get to different Activities. How do I do that? I read something about adapters but I am still not sure how to build this.

Here's my xml code for the TextView and the Button:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
    android:id="@+id/rl01">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width= "wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:id="@+id/text01"
        android:text="hello"
        android:textSize="24dp"
        android:textColor="@color/abc_search_url_text_normal"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"

        />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/text01"
        android:text="Press Me!"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 3):

The xml layout you have posted, will be used as each listview item.

Step 1: 
Create a class which extends BaseAdapter;

```
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter
{
    Context con;
    String[] data;
    public  CustomAdapter (Context context, String[] data)
    {
        this.con = context;

        this.data = data;

    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return data.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return data[position];
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }
//this method will be called for every item of your listview
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) con.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView= inflater.inflate(R.layout.customview, parent, false);
        TextView text = (TextView) view.findViewById(your text view id); //recognize your view like this
      text.setText(data[position]);
        return convertView;
 }

}
```

Step 2:
In your activity, recognize your listview:

```
yourListViewReference = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.your_list_view_id);
```

And initialize String array:

```
String[] data = {"item 1", "item2", "item3"}; //how many items you want
```

And then create instance of custom adapter you created, and set it to listview:

```
CustomAdapter ad = new CustomAdapter(this, data);
yourListViewReference.setAdapter(ad);
```

And sorry for my bad english. I am actually working on it.

Comment: Good answer! I'd just use the convertView to avoid inflating the view every time.

Comment: But I've read somewhere that it will be inflated everytime. I forgot the link. I  will crosscheck again. Thanks for this useful info.

Answer (score 0):

This [article](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html) from Vogella is really useful for what you want to do.

Basically, you'll create an Adapter that extends the BaseAdapter class as follows:

```
public class Adapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private List<Item> mItems;
    private Context mContext;

    public EventAdapter(Context context, List<Event> items) {
        mContext = context;
        mItems = items;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        // This recycles your view and prevents constant inflation, which can really hit your performance.
        View rowView = convertView;
        if (rowView == null) {
            ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.yourLayout, parent, false);
            viewHolder.text = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.yourTextViewId);
            viewHolder.button = (Button) rowView.findViewById(R.id.yourButtonId);
            rowView.setTag(viewHolder);
        }

        ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) rowView.getTag();

        // Get the correct item by position
        Item item = item.get(position);

        // Update the row layout with your item data
        holder.text.setText(item.text);
        holder.button.setButton(item.button);

        // Return your row view
        return rowView;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mItems.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
    }

    static class ViewHolder { 
        public TextView text;
        public Button button;
     }
```

Afterwards you just need to set this adapter to your ListView or RecyclerView by doing

```
listView.setAdapter(new Adapter(this, items));
```

Answer (score 0):

I would write a simple example:

You dont need a button in listview row, just implement  onItemClick();

main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
 >
   <ListView
        android:id="@+id/custom_list"
        android:longClickable="true"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   />



 </LinearLayout>
```

list_row.xml

```
<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
android:id="@+id/rl01">
<TextView
    android:layout_width= "wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:id="@+id/text01"
    android:text="hello"
    android:textSize="24dp"
    android:textColor="@color/abc_search_url_text_normal"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"

    />
```

MainActivity.java

```
oncreate()
{
 ....


  lv1 = (ListView) result.findViewById(R.id.custom_list);
  String[] listdata = {"txt1", "txt2", "txt3", "txt4", "txt5"};  
  ListAdapter listAdapt = new ListAdapter(this, listdata );
  lv1.setAdapter(listAdapt);
  lv1.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position, long id) {
 //do ur work here when list row selected 
        }
    });
 ..
}
```

ListAdapter.java

```
public class  ListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

String[] listData;
private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
public CustomListAdapter(Context aContext, String[] listData) {
    this.listData = listData;
    layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(aContext);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return listData.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return listData.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, null);

        TextView tv1 = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.text01);  

         tv1.setText(listData.[position]);

    return convertView;
}
```